Dark vertical lines in a transparent plot
I am using this code to create a transparent plot in Julia using Plots.jl.
using Plots
x = 1:10
plot(plot([sin, x -> sin(x + 0.25π)], x),
     plot([sin, x -> sin(x + 0.25π)], x), 
     layout = (1, 2), background_color = :transparent)
Plots.savefig("nobackground.pdf")

This is a screenshot of the PDF file that I get.

The left plot has dark vertical lines at 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, but the right plot does not have these dark vertical lines. The code that should produce the left plot and the right plot is identical. I see these dark vertical lines in macOS Preview and in Adobe Acrobat Reader. However, these dark vertical lines are not present if I export a PNG file which looks as follows (I just change the last line of the code to Plots.savefig("nobackground.png")).

Where do these dark vertical lines come from in the PDF file and what should I do to avoid these dark vertical lines in the PDF file?
Any help is much appreciated!

If you save as png are they still there?

@BallpointBen No, they ar not (I added a PNG image to my question to show how it looks like). These dark vertical lines are only present in the PDF file.

These lines also show up when using background_color = :transparent on Mac using Preview as viewer, so I guess it's a more general problem?

Reproducible on Skim (MacOS).

I did not found a workaround and opened an issue https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/4992.
